# Pod is still running after I delete the parent job

Tags: kubernetes

I created a job in my kubernetes cluster, the job takes a long time to finish, I decided to cancel it, so I deleted the job, but I noticed the associated pod is NOT automatically deleted. Is this the expected behavior? why is it not consistent with deployment deletion? Is there a way to make pod automatically deleted?

Comment: I believe this is incorrect, deleting the job should delete the associated pods.  Could it be that you removed labels so it could not find the pods?

Comment: @ergonaut I noticed in some cases the pod is deleted, it might have to do with the container or the process I run.

Comment: Can you post an example job that you are using, also how did your removed the job? Have you checked the event's on the leftover pod?

Comment: @Dagang Is the pod in "Terminating" status? You may have to forcefully delete it with something like `kubectl -n <namespace> delete pods <pod> --grace-period=0 --force` (`--force` is available in kubectl v1.5+). Check the value for `terminationGracePeriodSeconds` and adjust if it is too high. Also, don't know what the job does but perhaps changing the job to handle SIGTERM - the signal the containers in a pod get when the pod is being terminated - could help.

Answer (score 0):

If you're deleting a deployment, chances are you don't want any of the underlying pods, so it most likely forcefully deletes the pods by default.  Also, the desired state of pods would be unknown.

On the other hand if you're deleting a pod, it doesn't know what kind of replication controller may be attached to it and what it is doing next.  So it signals a shutdown to the container so that it can perhaps clean up gracefully.  There may be processes that are still using the pod, like a web request etc. and it would not be good to kill their request if it may take a second to complete.  This is what happens if you may be scaling up your pods or rolling out a new deployment, and you don't want any of the users to experience any downtime.  This is in fact one of the benefits of Kubernetes, as opposed to a traditional application server which requires you to shutdown the system to upgrade (or to play with load balancers to redirect traffic) which may negatively affect users.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, set propagation_policy to "Foreground", then pod is deleted right after job deleted.

Sample python code:

```
api_response = jobApiInstance.delete_namespaced_job(name=jobName, namespace=namespace, propagation_policy="Foreground")
```